# install doctrine 2.0 with composer.json

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I'm trying to install doctrine 2.0 with composer.

that's the tutorial i'm doing right now. I have problems to run this : " php composer.phar update

i get errors :

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img41/5687/consolec.png]
My config/Application.config.php:

```
<?php

// conﬁg/application.conﬁg.php:
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Album',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
         "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from your screenshot you have not [git](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/&ei=wvxSULOjMsTltQbo5oCYBQ&usg=AFQjCNH2T2_qw95k7pteod8BUEkDsBPnWg) installed or it is not in your path.
Install [git for windows](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/&ei=wvxSULOjMsTltQbo5oCYBQ&usg=AFQjCNH2T2_qw95k7pteod8BUEkDsBPnWg) and/or make sure you put the bin-directory of your installation in your path. Then try running composer.phar again.

Comment: Actually i don't have the rights to install a new soft, this is not my own computer.
Any chance to install it differently?
Thanks

Comment: Hm, try the portable version http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.7.11-preview20120710.7z&can=2&q= - I have no experience with this version.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can call `composer install` and `composer update` with the `--prefer-dist` flag. This will force composer to download the requirements as packages (usually a tarball or zip downloaded via HTTP) instead of cloning them using Git.